# How to specify 2 keys in python sorted(list)?

Tags: python, list, sorting, key

How do I sort a list of strings by `key=len` first then by `key=str`?
I've tried the following but it's not giving me the desired sort:

```
>>> ls = ['foo','bar','foobar','barbar']
>>> 
>>> for i in sorted(ls):
...     print i
... 
bar
barbar
foo
foobar
>>>
>>> for i in sorted(ls, key=len):
...     print i
... 
foo
bar
foobar
barbar
>>> 
>>> for i in sorted(ls, key=str):
...     print i
... 
bar
barbar
foo
foobar
```

I need to get:

```
bar
foo
barbar
foobar
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Define a key function that returns a tuple in which the first item is `len(str)` and the second one is the string itself. Tuples are then compared lexicographically. That is, first the lengths are compared; if they are equal then the strings get compared.

```
In [1]: ls = ['foo','bar','foobar','barbar']

In [2]: sorted(ls, key=lambda s: (len(s), s))
Out[2]: ['bar', 'foo', 'barbar', 'foobar']
```

Comment: just 2c if performance matters: a standalone function should be much faster than `lambda`.

Comment: @Eric - Duh... After testing it - I have to say there really isn't any performance difference.

Comment: Hm after testing it, I revoke my comment, no difference indeed. Was some bias of mine.

Answer (score 12):

The answer from *root* is correct, but you don't really need a *lambda*:

```
>>> def key_function(x):
        return len(x), str(x)

>>> sorted(['foo','bar','foobar','barbar'], key=key_function)
['bar', 'foo', 'barbar', 'foobar']
```

In addtion, there is a alternate approach takes advantage of sort stability which lets you sort in multiple passes (with the secondary key first):

```
>>> ls = ['foo','bar','foobar','barbar']
>>> ls.sort(key=str)                       # secondary key
>>> ls.sort(key=len)                       # primary key
```

See the [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html) for a good tutorial on Python sorting techniques.

Comment: Well, I would say there is no need for a full blown function here :) (BTW, you have a missing `, key=key_function)`)

Comment: When faced with a beginner question, I typically won't use a *lambda* in the answer and instead will use the most plain formulation of the answer.  If someone is asking this question about sorting and key functions, then it suggest that they are not already comfortable with *lambda*.

Comment: Point taken. I suppose I read it as of the use of *lambdas* in this context should be somehow discouraged in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use lambda:

```
from operator import itemgetter
ls = ['foo','bar','foobar','barbar']
print sorted([ [x,len(x)] for x in ls ] ,key=itemgetter(1,0))
# print [s[0] for s in sorted([ [x,len(x)] for x in ls ] ,key=itemgetter(1,0))]
```

Comment: This is uglier than the lambda because you are introducing cruft to the result which requires an extra `[0]` to access the result

Comment: Yes, this has x2 execution time compared to lambda

Comment: Also, for me the execution time with key_function is 1.2 times the lambda version

Answer (score 0):

Another form that works without a lambda:

```
>>> [t[1] for t in sorted((len(s),s) for s in ls)]
['bar', 'foo', 'barbar', 'foobar']
```

Comment: `key` was made so you don't need to use DSU